# Datastore: composite index not recognised

Tags: python-2.7, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've written a piece of code that adds and retrieves entities from the Datastore based on one filter (and order on the same property) - that worked fine. But when I tried adding filters for more properties, I got:

> PreconditionFailed: 412 no matching index found. recommended index is:
> - kind: Temperature
>   properties:
>   - name: DeviceID
>   - name: created

Eventually I figured out that I need to create index.yaml. Mine looks like this:

```
indexes:
- kind: Temperature
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: ID
  - name: created
  - name: Value
```

And it seems to be recognised, as the console shows:
[that it has been updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DSDO.png)
Yet when I run my code (specifically this part with two properties), it doesn't work (still getting the above-mentioned error) (the code is running on the Compute Engine).

```
query.add_filter('created', '>=', newStart)
query.add_filter('created', '<', newEnd)
query.add_filter('DeviceID', '=', devID)
query.order = ['created']
```

Trying to run the same query on the console produces

> Your Datastore does not have the composite index (developer-supplied) required for this query.

[error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIYd6.png) Search showed one other person who had the same issue and he managed to fix it by changing the order of the properties in the index.yaml, but that is not helping in my case. Has anybody encountered a similar problem or could help me with the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create the exact index suggested in the error message:

```
- kind: Temperature
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: DeviceID
  - name: created
```

Specifically, the first property in the index needs to be `DeviceID` instead of `ID` and the last property in the index needs to be the one you're using in the inequality filter (so you can't have `Value` as the last property in the index).

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I am even more confused how these composite indexes work. Your solution worked perfectly, but I wonder, why do I have to exclude "Value" from index.yaml? Is it because only properties that will be used for sorting/ordering have to be there?

Comment: It's an implementation detail of how indexes work. They are "sparse", so entities with no `Value` property would not appear in your index and the query might incorrectly omit some results.